# Rotate Data for Gridding

Tags: qgis, vector-grid

I have sample data that was collected in lines.  I would like to rotate the data to North-South so that I can rasterize it, then back to the original NAD83 Zone Projection where it's situated at an angle from North.

[image]

Comment: The term will be `Affine transformation`. BTW, how about using `v.mkgrid` in the Processing Toolbox - GRASS? This tool can create oriented vector grid in one action.

Comment: GRASS doesn't appear to be installed properly, I'll see what I can do with a re-install of qgis

Comment: I am on Windows10 so it may be different from your environment...GRASS tools become available when I start `QGIS Desktop with GRASS` in the QGIS folder.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm also on Windows.  Why are they separated like that?  Is there any advantage to using QGIS wihtout GRASS?

Comment: I've edited my question to show my intended result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Grid (Nearest Neighbor) does this already.  I had misread the input titled "Angle of seach ellipse rotation in degrees (counter clockwise)".  In this I just need to put the angle of my data and the raster is calculated properly.

[image]